# Unzipping a file with PHP, but not all files are extracted

Tags: php, zip, wamp

I'm working on extracting a zip archive with PHP. The structure of the archive is seven folders, each of which contains on the order of 10,000 files, each around 1 kB.

My code is pretty simple and uses the ZipArchive class:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$result = $zip->open($filename);
if ($result === true) {
    $zip->extractTo($tmpdir);
    $zip->close();
}
```

The problem I'm having, though, is that the extraction seems to halt. The first folder is fully extracted, but only about half of the second one is. None of the other five are extracted at all.

I also tried using this code, which breaks it into chunks of 10 kB at a time, but got the exact same result:

```
$archive = zip_open($filename);
while ($entry = zip_read($archive)) {
    $size = zip_entry_filesize($entry);
    $name = zip_entry_name($entry);
    if (substr($name, -1) == '/') {
        if (!file_exists($tmpdir . $name)) mkdir($tmpdir . $name);
    } else {
        $unzipped = fopen($tmpdir . $name, 'wb');
        while ($size > 0) {
            $chunkSize = ($size > 10240) ? 10240 : $size;
            $size -= $chunkSize;
            $chunk = zip_entry_read($entry, $chunkSize);
            if ($chunk !== false) fwrite($unzipped, $chunk);
        }
        fclose($unzipped);
    }
}
```

I've also tried increasing the memory limit in PHP from 512 MB to 1024 MB, but again got the same result. Unzipped everything is around 100 MB, so I wouldn't anticipate it being a memory issue anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Probably its your max execution time... disable the limit completely by setting it to 0 or set a good value.

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 10000);
```

... dont set it to 0 in production use ...

If you don't have access to ini_set() because of the disable_function directive you may have to edit its value in your php.ini directly.

Comment: I already have a call to set_time_limit(), and the script continues to process everything past the extraction without trouble.